# How to create automatic launchd job that sets the Ruby version to use

Tags: macos, launchd, ruby

I’d like to run a ruby script automatically once or twice a day on my MacBook running OS X Yosemite.

Problem is that I currently have three versions of Ruby on my system including 1.8.7 and 2.2.1, neither of which the script will run with. So I say `rvm use system` which switches to a different version, though I don’t know how to find out which one (as `rvm current` just replies “system”). And then I can run the script happily.

However, when I create this little script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rvm use system
/Users/jonathan/Library/Scripts/slogger/slogger
```

It won’t run from the shell, saying:

> RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
>   You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
>   Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.

I know how to create and set basic launchd jobs; but I don’t know how to set the ruby version for the created process if I can’t include it in a script in this way. I’m sure it must be possible, though…

Comment: Why not use the full path to the required ruby - or create ruby18 runby22 as scripts to call the correct ruby

Answer (score 1):

This is untested (as I don’t use `rvm`), but there should be two simple ways to fix this.

1. Source `rvm` in your script (which you likely do anyway in your `.profile`, or `.bashrc`, or equivalent):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   [[ -s "${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
   rvm use system
   /Users/jonathan/Library/Scripts/slogger/slogger
   ```

   That new line is a shorter way of saying

   ```
   if [[ -s "${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]]; then
     source "${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
   fi
   ```

   `-s` is used to return “[True if `FILE` exists and has a size greater than zero](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html)”.
2. And you’ll probably laugh as to how easy it was to fix, simply do what the message says and use `/bin/bash --login`, like so:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash --login
   rvm use system
   /Users/jonathan/Library/Scripts/slogger/slogger
   ```